# Do I need to install docker engine on proxmox's LXC to run a portainer agent?

Tags: docker, proxmox, containers, lxc

Currently I am running Proxmox and have installed the docker-engine and Portainer on the main Proxmox node. I would like to add more environments, including an LXC which I downloaded from a template that came from Proxmox.

My question is, can I install the portainer agent on this LXC without installing the docker engine on it first? installing a docker engine on every LXC to manage it through portainer seems unnecessary at first glance. I'm new to containers, docker, and proxmox and anybody that could shed some light as to how these layers operate would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you checkout https://tteck.github.io/Proxmox/ for scripts on installing different Containers and other goodies for Proxmox.. The docker install script also has the option to install portainer. This should save you some headaches, and you can also deconstruct the scripts of you want to see what it is doing behind the scenes.